# Liquibase with SVN - PHP/MySQL projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, liquibase

Today I found `LiquiBase` project and I think it is very interesting. I would like to use it but I am looking for best way to do it.

We are working with `PHP` projects and `SVN` (a few developers) with one `MySQL` server.

I am wondering how to work with LiquiBase:

- should we store its changeLog in SVN too ?
- how to edit this changeLog ? Any `IDE` for `Linux` ? Plugin for `Eclipse` is not available.
- any post-commit script to apply changes ? What about LiquiBase`s error logs ?

Thank you for any sugestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should store the changelogs in your version control system.
Your favorite text editor (or xml editor) should be enough.

here are many ways to execute your change log including via [command line](http://liquibase.org/manual/command_line), [Ant](http://liquibase.org/manual/Ant), [Maven](http://liquibase.org/manual/Maven), [Grails](http://liquibase.org/manual/grails), and a [servlet listener](http://liquibase.org/manual/servlet_listener).

Comment: Ok, so everyone should learn `LiquiBase` statement. But what about about executing `LiquiBase`'s scripts and error logs ?

Comment: Generally everyone would need to execute the liquibase scripts in order to update their local development environments.  As part of executing the scripts, they would need to watch the error log to make sure nothing failed in the database update.